# How to use Jquery in XSLT 1.0

Tags: jquery, xml, rss, xslt-1.0

I have been trying to use jquery in xslt 1.0 but I am unable to get it work.
I am new to xslt and not sure how to use it.

I have tried enclosed codes:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ddwrt msxsl rssaggwrt" 
           xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
           xmlns:rssaggwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/rssagg/runtime"
           xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
           xmlns:rssFeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart"
           xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
           xmlns:rss1="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
           xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"
           xmlns:atom2="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">

<xsl:param name="rss_FeedLimit">5</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_ExpandFeed">false</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_LCID">1033</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_WebPartID">RSS_Viewer_WebPart</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_alignValue">left</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_IsDesignMode">False</xsl:param>

 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        <div class="slm-layout-main" >            

        <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.body">
            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

        </div> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <![CDATA[
        $('.RssNewContent1').each(function()
            {
                //alert("test");
                var height = parseInt($(this).css("height"));

                 var content = $(this).html();
                 while (this.scrollHeight > height)
                 {
                       content = content.replace(/\s+\S*$/, "");
                       $(this).html(content + " " + "...");
                 }
            });

        ]]>
        </script>         
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
        <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />  

        <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">


                    <div class="RssNewContent1" >

                        <a href = "{link}" target="_blank">
                            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                        </a>
     <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes"  select="string(description)" />
    </div>


               </div>       
           </xsl:if>              
        </xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: My personal suggestion: don't use XSLT. The bugs in different browser's implementations of it aren't being fixed because it's considered a dead technology. Instead, use AJAX and parse the needed data out of the XML into your own HTML document.

Comment: @NewGirlInCalgary How does it fail exactly?

Comment: @Louis it doesn't do anything. It does not show me alert box even. If I remove everything and just write alert(); it doesn't work that even. I am not sure what it is I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Blazemonger I am using RSS webpart in sharepoint 2007. This XSLT is from that webpart. I need to edit the XSLT and make some modification. Therefore I can't write my own ajax code to parse the RSS feed.

Comment: @NewGirlInCalgary "It doesn't do anything" to me means that the result of the transformation is nothing, an empty string. If this is the case, then your problem is much broader than how to produce jQuery code with XSLT.

Comment: @Louis I get the result from XSLT. It is not an empty string. But its jquery who doesn't work and doesn't do anything on result set. I can use CSS easily but jquery doesn't work. XSLT gives me RSS feed result with its title, image and description. I am trying to handle the number of lines showing for description using jquery. My code does work separately but not in xslt.  Therefore, I am not sure why it is not working. Hope it does make some sense. I am so sorry for not describing it before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<xsl:comment><![CDATA[
         $('.RssNewContent1').each(function()
            {
                //alert("test");
                var height = parseInt($(this).css("height"));

                 var content = $(this).html();
                 while (this.scrollHeight > height)
                 {
                       content = content.replace(/\s+\S*$/, "");
                       $(this).html(content + " " + "...");
                 }
            });
    //]]></xsl:comment>
</script>
```